# Data from Checkboxes does not store in database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, checkbox

My checkboxes does not store in the database table that i have
Here is the whole code..

The code that i use for the insert into is this

```
queryMysql("INSERT INTO patient_diseases (disease,username) VALUES('$disease','$username')");
```

and my checkboxes code is this...

```
<?php
  $sql = "SELECT name FROM disease";
  $query_resource = mysql_query($sql);
  while( $name = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_resource) ):
?>
    <span><?php echo $name['name']; ?></span>
    <input type="checkbox" name="disease[]" value="<?php echo $name['name']; ?>" /><br />

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

What is wrong with the code?
I had the same code for the insert into for the dropdown list and it worked fine but then i was asked to change it to checkboxes and now it doesnt store the selected values

Also i am getting this error Notice: Array to string conversion in `E:\xampp\htdocs\ptixiaki\signup.php on line 50 and the line 50` is this `queryMysql("INSERT INTO patient_diseases (disease,username) VALUES('$disease','$username')");`

And it store in my data this
[image]

Why it stores Array in the disease column and why it doesn't store all the selected checkboxes

Comment: what is so difficult changing to checkboxes?

Comment: Do you want them to only be able to select one option? Because if you do, it might be better to use radio buttons instead of checkboxes.

Comment: @The42ndDoctor no I want to choose as many as the checkboxes are

Comment: @charlietfl I cannot find the way to display the checkboxes with the values that I have in my database

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6944865/dynamically-creating-checkboxes

Comment: @Maximus2012 I edited my code and I have a problem , can you take a look at it? Please :)

Comment: value="<?php echo $name['name']; ?>  should be value="<?php echo $name['name']; ?>" (ending double quote)

Comment: @Maximus2012 thank you it works but how to store them because i am getting this error `Notice: Array to string conversion in E:\xampp\htdocs\ptixiaki\signup.php on line 50` and the line 50 is this `queryMysql("INSERT INTO patient_diseases (disease,username) VALUES('$disease','$username')");`

Comment: @Maximus2012 if i change `$disease` to `$name` then it doesnt store anything

Comment: What does queryMysql() function do? Is it a custom function that you built ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74659/discussion-between-niklakis-and-maximus2012).

Comment: @Maximus2012 It is a function in order to INSERT data to database. It worked with the dropdown list but with the checkboxes it doesnt . If you want join the chat

Comment: You need to post all the code that you might have. I would say try using mysqli_ functions to insert data in place of your own custom function. At the very least post the code for your custom function and indicate what part of the code is giving you error.

Comment: @Maximus2012 I post the whole code and the part that we worked

Comment: I think you have too much complicated code. I would recommend that you simplify your code and work on each part step by step, make sure it is working and then add additional code. Some of your custom functions might be giving problem but I am not sure.

Comment: You might want to try using stand along mysqli_ function rather than writing your own custom functions at this stage to minimize issues with the code.

Comment: @Maximus2012 The rest of the code is working fine , what is stored in my database table for the diseases is this (http://prntscr.com/6quilw)

Comment: @ninetwozero Hi am using your answer from this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6944865/dynamically-creating-checkboxes) but I have a problem ! Can you help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was the below..
It was one line of code

```
$disease = implode(",",$_POST["disease"]);

 queryMysql("INSERT INTO patient_diseases (disease,username) VALUES('$disease','$username')");
```